# Converting CassandraRow obtained from joinWithCassandraTable to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

```
case class SourcePartition(id: String, host:String ,bucket: Int)
joinedRDDs =partitions.joinWithCassandraTable("db_name","table_name")
joinedRDDs.values.foreach(println)
```

I have to use joinWithCassandraTable , How do i covert the result CassandraRow in to a DataFrame?  OR is there any equivalent of joinWithCassandraTable with DataFrame ?

I have to read a lot of partitions in one go,  I'm aware of Datastax Cassandra connector Predicate push down, but it allows to pull only one Partition at a time ( It doesnt seems to allow IN operator , Only = seems to be supported)

Answer (score 0):

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[4]").appName("RDD2DF").getOrCreate()
    val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext

    import spark.implicits._

    val internalJoinRDD = spark.sparkContext.cassandraTable("test", "test_table_1").joinWithCassandraTable("test", "table_table_2")
    internalJoin.toDebugString

    internalJoinRDD.toDF()
```

Can you try the above code snippet.

If you have a schema for your data, you can use

```
def createDataFrame(internalJoinRDD: RDD[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame
```